# UnresolvedAddressException with MLlib/Spark

Tags: java, networking, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

When I'm running MLlib for files > 1 partition in our cluster I get the following exception:

> 16/08/14 12:43:23 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 2.1 (TID
>   49, da06.qcri.org): FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(3, da08.qcri.org,
>   33322), shuffleId=0, mapId=5, reduceId=2, message=
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Failed to connect to
>   da08.qcri.org:33322   at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:323)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:51)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)  at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)    at
>   org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineCombinersByKey(Aggregator.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:83)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:98)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)    at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to ***.org:33322   at
>   org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.access$200(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher$1.run(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:170)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     ... 3
>   more
>
> Caused by: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:123)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:621)  at
>   io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:209)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.connect(AbstractNioChannel.java:207)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1097)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:471)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:456)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.connect(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:47)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:471)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:456)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.connect(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:50)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeConnect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:471)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:456)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.connect(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:438)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.connect(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:908)
>     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.connect(AbstractChannel.java:203)
>     at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$2.run(Bootstrap.java:166)   at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
>     ... 1 more

In the slaves configuration file, I have the nodes by IP and not by hostname. In addition, when I ping the machines from the master node using the hostname, it does not seem to have any issue.

Anyone had a similar issue or has some idea on how to solve it?